# A word that is the past participle for having become something

Tags: past-tense

I want to say:

> As someone who has recently become a father, ...

but I would like to use the shorter form:

> As a recently ____ father, ...

What word could I use here?  "Become", "becomed", "emerged", "materialised" and "born" don't seem to fit.

In a different example, we might be able to use the word "graduated":

> As a recently ____ engineer, ...

But what if we wanted to say only that someone had *become* an engineer, without specifying the actual process of graduation or training?

Comment: We normally just say "new". As a new father...as a new engineer

Comment: A very reasonable question, but I think you'll have to make do with the original (or Tim's alternative).

Comment: I can't find the exact collocation with ***recently***, but ***newly*** is contextually synonymous, and Google Books has dozens of written instances of [*newly **fledged** engineer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22newly+fledged+engineer%22). Plus there are several hits for [*newly fledged **father***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22newly+fledged+father%22) (so it doesn't only get used of new states you had to *study, develop, train* to attain).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "newly minted father" has more google books hits than @FumbleFingers' suggestion of "newly fledged father". I think both of these phrases would be fine.

These are both metaphorical, but I think if you want a non-metaphorical past participle with this meaning, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there isn't any conjugated form of "to become" that will fit in that blank space - here's why (I think):

In your example *As a recently graduated engineer*, or for that matter *As a recently trained engineer*, "graduated" and "trained" are perfect *passive* participles - ie. It is you who has been trained and has been graduated (I'm pretty sure "to graduate" is transitive in this case).

When you attempt to substitute in some form of "to become," if I'm not mistaken, it's impossible because "to become" has no passive forms (and thus no perfect passive participle, unlike "to train" or "to graduate").

Instead, try:
"Having recently become a father..."
This way, you would be using the perfect active participle of "to become," which does in fact exist.

Answer (score -1):

I would say:

> As a *newborn* engineer

or

> As a *newborn* father

Apple dictionary defines *newborn* as:

> A recently born child or animal. Figurative: a newborn star.

Hope this helps.